# get query grouped by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these table:

```
server ocurrences date
A      122        20200101
B      1          20200101
C      15         20200101
............
```

I'm tring to get these result:

```
                A;B;C
20200101        122;1;15
```

I make these query:

```
select server, ocurrences, date FROM NET_REPORT 
where to_char(date,'YYYYMMDD') >= '20200101' 
AND server IN ('A','B','C') GROUP BY date, server,ocurrences ORDER BY date,server;
```

But I can't get what I want. 
Could you help me please? 
Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should not store `date` values in `varchar` or `text` columns.

Comment: maybe this? `SELECT date,array_agg(server),array_agg(occurences) FROM t 
WHERE to_char(date,'YYYYMMDD') >= '20200101' 
GROUP BY date;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `string_agg()` or `array_agg()`.  I strongly recommend the latter:

```
select date, array_agg(server) as servers,
       array_agg(ocurrences) as occurrences
from net_report 
where date >= '2020-01-01' and
      date < '2020-01-02' and
      server in ('des', 'pre', 'prod') 
group by date
order by date;
```

Comment: Line 2 gives me an error: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Anyway I don' explain very well. I don't care if they are separated by commas or each one in a column.

Comment: @absolute333 . . . I fixed the typo.  I originally wrote with `string_agg()` but realized that `array_agg()` is a better solution (in general, although not necessarily for your particular use-case).